# REST API call not populating table with array contents

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

I have a query that fires off when a user goes to a page, which returns the on-shift points of contact for escalations.  The issue I'm experiencing is that nothing is being populated into the table I have designated for these POCs.  I've added my code below, including the HTML element this should be populating into, but I get no errors thrown back in the console, and I know that there is data that should populate into this as I've run the Ajax query and looked through the XML results and I can see entries that should show.  I have another call on the same page that contacts another list to retrieve on-going critical incidents and that one works without any issues, so I've convinced myself that it's the `.innerHTML` part that's causing the issue, as the initial `.innerHTML = "";` command is clearing the Placeholder text, however nothing else is being completed.

```js
    var filManager = [];
    var mancontact = document.getElementById("managercontact");

    function getContacts() {
        $.ajax({
            url: ".../_api/web/lists/getbytitle('On Shift Contacts')/items?$filter=Status eq 'In'&$select=Title,Id,Role,Status,Number,Brand",
            type: "GET",
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
            },
            success: function(data) {
                filManager = data.d.results;
                filManager = filManager.filter(function(item) {
                    return item.Role == "Incident Manager";
                });
                if (filManager === undefined || filManager == 0) {
                    mancontact.innerHTML = "<tr><td style='font-family:Calibri'><center>There are currently no on-shift Managers</center></td></tr>";
                } else {
                    mancontact.innerHTML = "";
                    mancontact += "<tr style='font-family:Calibri;font-size:14pt;text-align:center'><td colspan='3'>Manager On-Shift</td></tr><tr style='font-family:Calibri;font-size:12pt;text-align:center'><td>Name</td><td>Contact Number</td><td>Location</td></tr>";
                    for (var obj in filManager) {
                        mancontact.innerHTML += "<tr style='font-family:Calibri;font-size:12pt;text-align:center'><td>" + filManager[obj].Title + "</td><td>" + filManager[obj].Number + "</td><td>" + filManager[obj].Brand + "</td></tr>";
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

```html
<center>
  <table id="managercontact">
    <tr>
      <td>Placeholder</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</center>
```

example array output from the call:

```
filManager = [
{ID:"1", Title: "Person1", Status: "In", Role: "Incident Controller", Brand: "Consumer", Number: "01234 567 890"},
{ID:"2", Title: "Person2", Status: "In", Role: "Incident Manager", Brand: "Consumer", Number: "01234 567 890"},
{ID:"3", Title: "Person3", Status: "Off", Role: "Incident Manager", Brand: "Business", Number: "01234 567 890"},
{ID:"4", Title: "Person4", Status: "Off", Role: "Incident Controller", Brand: "Business", Number: "01234 567 890"},];
```

Comment: consider giving the json returned by your server. We can't do anything with your ajax call. Btw, if no errors, filter will return an array (potentially empty), so testing for undefined is useless, and testing for 0 as well since an array is not 0. (you should test solely for filManager.length === 0)

Comment: I've added an example of the data the ajax call returns, however I believe I've resolved the issue as there was a missing ```.innerHTML``` in the else section.

Comment: The example output seems wrong, its missing quotation marks around text values.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a missing `innerHTML` in the if statement.  Adding in the below code instead of the if statement above has resolved this issue for me.

````
            mancontact.innerHTML = "<tr><td style='font-family:Calibri'><center>There are currently no on-shift Managers</center></td></tr>";
            } else {
            mancontact.innerHTML = "";
            mancontact.innerHTML += "<tr style='font-family:Calibri;font-size:14pt;text-align:center'><td colspan='3'>Manager On-Shift</td></tr><tr style='font-family:Calibri;font-size:12pt;text-align:center'><td>Name</td><td>Contact Number</td><td>Location</td></tr>";
            for(var obj in filManager){
                mancontact.innerHTML += "<tr style='font-family:Calibri;font-size:12pt;text-align:center'><td>" + filManager[obj].Title + "</td><td>" + filManager[obj].Number + "</td><td>" + filManager[obj].Brand + "</td></tr>";
            }```
````